# the accessToken of the GoogleSignInAuthentication accessToken is null in the web flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin, flutter-web

I am trying to make the web version of my application available in flutter. In the mobile version, both on android and ios, login with google credentials works perfectly. In the web flutter I get the idToken correctly but the accessToken is null.

I followed the steps in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HLt1TYA600&list=LLe08PibNO0_PFjUVIu5WcxQ&index=3&t=1681s

```
Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
        print(">>> accessToken");
        print(googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);
        print(">>> idToken");
        print(googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);
        if (googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken != null &&
            googleSignInAuthentication.idToken != null) {
        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        );

        final AuthResult authResult =
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

        final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
        return _userFromFirebase(user);
        } else {
          throw PlatformException(
            code: 'ERROR_MISSING_GOOGLE_AUTH_TOKEN',
            message: 'Missing Google Auth Token',
          );
        }
      } else {
        throw PlatformException(
          code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
          message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem! What's weird is that I have another project that was made for web and it works fine, yet my mobile app broke when I tried to bring it to web. Any luck?

Comment: not yet. I'll open a issue on flutter github.

Comment: If it helps, on web only you can use `FirebaseAuth.signInWithPopup` and pass `GoogleAuthProvider()` as an argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3276) on GitHub last night and got an answer:

> Hey, please update to firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1 - there was a bug with the assertion that was fixed.
> Latest versions can be seen here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#2-update-firebase-plugins

To clarify, the problem isn't that that the `accessToken` is null, it's that it doesn't have to be non-null. The error is that there is an assert to check if **either** `idToken` or `accessToken` is not null, but really it checks that **both** are not null.

For completeness, [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/3216/files#diff-be71096f90f1a879f17b7c94607b0885R81) is the exact line change that fixes this bug. Notice how they changed from checking `accessToken != null && idToken != null` to `accessToken != null || idToken != null`.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the latest release of firebase_auth which is firebase_auth 1.4.1 and still having this problem !

Comment: i cant get the access code either. i get the ID token but i need the access token.

Answer (score 0):

For authentication via the flutter web app, unlike the android app, you need to define the scope required in order to get a valid access code. If you don't define the scope, the access code will be null. Here is the code that worked for me:

this is a small class to make use of the google_sign_in_dart package from flutter dev:

```
class GoogleSignInApi{

  static List<String> scopes = <String>[
    'email',

  ];

  static final _clientIDWeb = '5860xxxxxxx------xxxxxx (redacted)';
//for Web you also need to define clientId, and the scopes
  static final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(clientId: _clientIDWeb, scopes:scopes);
  static Future <GoogleSignInAccount?>login() => _googleSignIn.signIn();
  static Future logout() => _googleSignIn.disconnect();


}
```

Then when calling login:

```
  final user = await GoogleSignInApi.login();

  final googleAuth = await user!.authentication;

  if (user == null)
    {
      customshowDialog(c, "Login Failed", "Login request failed.");
    } else
      customshowDialog(c, "Login Success", user!.email.toString()+" Access Token is:"+ googleAuth.accessToken.toString());
```